# Is it possibile to generate a whole schema example with springfox?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

Is it possible to generate a whole schema example with springfox?

I'm using spring boot with springfox and can't seem to find a way to generate the result as described on the swagger specification website.

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/adding-examples/

An example can be specified for the entire schema (including all nested schema), provided that the example conforms to the schema.

```
definition:
  CatalogItem:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
      name:
        type: string
      image:
        type: object
        properties:
          url:
            type: string
          width:
            type: integer
          height:
            type: integer
    required:
      - id
      - name
    example:   # <----------
      id: 38
      name: T-shirt
      image:
        url: images/38.png
        width: 100
        height: 100
```